# When are Debian questions off topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just voted to close [this Debian question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15876/whats-eating-my-memory-closed). There are a bunch of Debian questions that are open though; when is it appropriate to close a Debian question?

Comment: Now that [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) has launched, it could be a migration path from Ask Ubuntu, if too many Linux-but-not-Ubuntu questions get asked here.

Answer (score 14):

I think that Debian user-style questions be flagged so it can be migrated to [unix.se](http://unix.stackexchange.com).

However, in the case of questions that focus on how to work with Debian, like these should be most welcome:

- [How is Ubuntu different from Debian?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1336/how-is-ubuntu-different-from-debian)
- [How do I propose my project to be part of Debian too?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13255/how-do-i-propose-my-project-to-be-part-of-debian-too)
- [Tools to diff deb-src packages between ubuntu and debian repos](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15220/tools-to-diff-deb-src-packages-between-ubuntu-and-debian-repos)

So I was thinking something like this for criteria:

- Does it help people understand our working relationship and the importance of Debian?
- Is it something that will help contributors work with Debian better?